# Trowing InvocationTargetException trying to make new instance of String

Tags: java, reflection, invocationtargetexception

I'am trying to make new instance of String class and i got Exception in some cases.
Like when i'am making a constructor of 4 parameters (byte[],int,int,int) i got it and when i'am making constructor of 2 parameters everything is ok.

```
public static Object makeNewInstance(Constructor<?> con) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException{
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Class<?>[] paraListTypes = con.getParameterTypes();

        Object[] valArr = new Object[paraListTypes.length];


        for(int i=0;i<paraListTypes.length ; i++){
            if(paraListTypes[i].isPrimitive()){
                System.out.println("Enter " + paraListTypes[i].toString() + " value:");
                valArr[i] = getOneValue(paraListTypes[i].toString());
            }
            else if(paraListTypes[i].isArray()){
                valArr[i] = makeNewArray(paraListTypes[i]);
            }
            else{
                System.out.println(paraListTypes[i]);
                valArr[i] = printAllConstructorsAndChooseOne(paraListTypes[i]);

            }
        }
        try{

        return con.newInstance(valArr);
        }

        catch(InvocationTargetException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return null;


    }
```

the full track trace that is get is:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) at labs.Ref.makeNewInstance(Ref.java:75) at labs.Ref.main(Ref.java:161) Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 9 at java.lang.String.checkBounds(Unknown Source) ... 7 more –

Comment: Post the full stack trace and show us how you are using this method. Give us a reproducible example.

Comment: You can edit your question. Add all of the information there.

Comment: Give us inputs. We don't know what `Constructor` argument you passed. We don't know what `getOneValue`, `makeNewArray`, or `printAllConstructorsAndChooseOne` do.

Comment: Note that the `String` constructor you are trying to use is deprecated.

Comment: is there a way to know if the constructor is deprecated using reflection ?

Comment: Check if the class has the `@Deprecated` annotation.

Comment: thank i found it , but still i got the problem that constructor public java.lang.String(byte[],int) @java.lang.Deprecated() is not throwing anything and java.lang.String(byte[],int,int,int) @java.lang.Deprecated()  is crashing

Answer (score 1):

The last 2 parameters of the 4 parameters constructor of `String` are an offset and a length to make a `String` from a `byte` array. Check that offset + length isn't greater than array's lenght.

If you do, for example:

```
new String("hola".getBytes(), 0,0,5);
```

you'll get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 5
at java.lang.String.checkBounds(String.java:375)
at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:314)
at Tmp.main(Tmp.java:13)
```

exactly the same that you'd get but the `InvocationTargetException` because you used reflection.

Hope it helps.